# Uncover a multiline equation with beamer

Tags: beamer, equations

I am using the `beamer` class for a presentation and `amsmath` package for the math mode.
If I uncover the formula in the following way, the formula jumps between slides, which is not intended.

```
\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{
    \begin{multline*}
    S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
    + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} 
    \end{multline*}}
    \only<2->{
    \begin{multline*}
    S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
    \xcancel{+ \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} }
    \end{multline*}}
\end{frame}
```

if I uncover its specific part directly, the alignment fails for the first slide and is only correct in the second slide (I tried also with `\shoveright` :( ):

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{multline*}
S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
\uncover<1>{+ \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t}} 
\uncover<2->{\xcancel{+ \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t}}} 
\end{multline*}
\end{frame}
```

So my question is: How do I uncover multiline equations within `beamer`?

Comment: Bort, please always give a full and compilable example. It is normally just a few lines longer, but avoids guesses which packages you used. I had to look up the `cancel` package by myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\only`s for exclusive material, but the `overprint` environment together with `\onslide`. It ensures that the required size is reserved on any of the slides and therefore avoids most issues with jumping text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} 
    \end{multline*}
        \onslide<2>
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        \xcancel{+ \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} }
    \end{multline*}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

This should answer your question about how to uncover multiline equations within beamer. However, the `\xcancel` macro still causes the second line to jump up, which is a different problem.

Comment: thank you very much... this solves the problem. Instead of canceling I change the textcolor to light gray and problem is solved. Oh, yes sorry for the packages. I  copied this from a longer document and forgot  about the header.

Answer (score 7):

I must admit that I hate typing out stuff more than once, so I don't like either solution so far presented!  So here's a variation on Hendrik's solution that works by making the `\xxcancel` command overlay-aware.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand<>{\xxcancel}[1]{\alt#2{\xcancel{#1}\vphantom{#1}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        \xxcancel<2->{{} + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} }
    \end{multline*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, great! So `\alt` does the trick here; you may want to emphasize that in your answer (that should be the accepted one!). Why does `\alt` work better than `\only`?

Comment: @Hendrik: Well, `\alt` is what you want in this case since you want the cancellation replaced by the under text.  Also, it's acting in two different ways: the `\only`s in the question are outside the mathematics but the `\alt` is inside.  I guess it's pure luck (or good design) that the `\xcancel` doesn't seem to add any extra space so the equation doesn't jump about on the page, otherwise something more complicated would be needed (not knowing of the cancel package, I use TikZ to draw big lines across the page for this sort of thing).

Comment: @Andrew: No, the `\xcancel` _does_ give different vertical spacing; otherwise the `\vphantom` wouldn't be needed. So it's really that `\alt` is better here. Wasn't obvious to me that it's inside the math; maybe that's why it's better.

Comment: @Hendrik: Actually, my original statement is correct: `\xcancel` doesn't **add** any extra space!  It's a little odd that it _removes_ some, which is what your `\vphantom` corrects for.  This is actually quite a complicated question as there are several distinct issues: uncovering mathematics, ensuring that nothing jumps, and making a command overlay-aware.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I also found that odd. But I insist that `\xcancel` **does** add (negative) vertical space! `;-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: I concede.

Answer (score 2):

Martin essentially gave you what you need. Here's how you can prevent the second line from jumping up:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand\xxcancel[1]{\xcancel{#1}\vphantom{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t}
    \end{multline*}
        \onslide<2>
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        \xxcancel{{} + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} }
    \end{multline*}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Making the second line *not* jump revealed that the `+` in the second line moved; to prevent this, I added `{}` in front of it.