# Beamer alt command like visible instead of like only

Tags: beamer, overlays

The `beamer` command `\alt<*overlay specification*>{foo}{bar}` will insert `foo` if the current slide is within the given overlay specification, and `bar` otherwise.  It's equivalent to

```
\only<*overlay specification*>{foo}\only<*complementary overlay specification*>{bar}
```

Here is a sample document using it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1} \\
\ln y &= \ln (x^2+1) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(x+3) - \ln(x-1) \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}
      &= \frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\end{align*}
So
\[
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right)
\alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}
\end{split}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is very useful and saves typing.  But if one of the alternatives is larger than the other, it leads to jiggling slides.

What I would like is a overlay-specification-aware command `\altvisible` that would take the same amount of space on each slide.  So it would have to insert a box as big as the bigger of the two, and then set the correct material.  So the above document with `\altvisible` instead of `\alt` would not jiggle.

Any takers?

Comment: Take a look at [Uncover a multiline equation with beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11571/1235). Do the answers to this question help you?

Comment: Such things are normally done using `overprint`, but I only used it for whole lines/paragraphs, never for short material. See my answer at the question liked by Hendrik.

Comment: @Hendrik, @Martin: Thanks for the pointers.  `overprint` is relevant, but because my particular use case is within a math expression it's not flexible enough.  `overlayarea` might work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following up the discussion of diabonas answer, here my suggestion. The idea to use phantom boxes seems the way to go. Here the two alternatives are boxed so that they can be measured. The code could be improved to detect the mode (text, math, display math, etc.) by itself and avoid the re-boxing which happens in the phantom commands.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>\Alt[2]{{%
    \sbox0{$\displaystyle #1$}%
    \sbox1{$\displaystyle #2$}%
    \alt#3%
        {\rlap{\usebox0}\vphantom{\usebox1}\hphantom{\ifnum\wd0>\wd1 \usebox0\else\usebox1\fi}}%
        {\rlap{\usebox1}\vphantom{\usebox0}\hphantom{\ifnum\wd0>\wd1 \usebox0\else\usebox1\fi}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1} \\
\ln y &= \ln (x^2+1) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(x+3) - \ln(x-1) \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}
      &= \frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\end{align*}
So
\[
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right)
\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}
\end{split}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Here the version which checks the mode and math-style automatically. It works in all math and text modes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
% Detect mode. mathpalette is used to detect the used math style
\newcommand<>\Alt[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \ifmmode
        \expandafter\mathpalette
        \expandafter\math@Alt
    \else
        \expandafter\make@Alt
    \fi
    {{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    \endgroup
}

% Un-brace the second argument (required because \mathpalette reads the three arguments as one
\newcommand\math@Alt[2]{\math@@Alt{#1}#2}

% Set the two arguments in boxes. The math style is given by #1. \m@th sets \mathsurround to 0.
\newcommand\math@@Alt[3]{%
    \setbox\z@ \hbox{$\m@th #1{#2}$}%
    \setbox\@ne\hbox{$\m@th #1{#3}$}%
    \@Alt
}

% Un-brace the argument
\newcommand\make@Alt[1]{\make@@Alt#1}

% Set the two arguments into normal boxes
\newcommand\make@@Alt[2]{%
    \sbox\z@ {#1}%
    \sbox\@ne{#2}%
    \@Alt
}

% Place one of the two boxes using \rlap and place a \phantom box with the maximum of the two boxes
\newcommand\@Alt[1]{%
    \alt#1%
        {\rlap{\usebox0}}%
        {\rlap{\usebox1}}%
    \setbox\tw@\null
    \ht\tw@\ifnum\ht\z@>\ht\@ne\ht\z@\else\ht\@ne\fi
    \dp\tw@\ifnum\dp\z@>\dp\@ne\dp\z@\else\dp\@ne\fi
    \wd\tw@\ifnum\wd\z@>\wd\@ne\wd\z@\else\wd\@ne\fi
    \box\tw@
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Test the different modes and math styles
\begin{frame}
Display:
\[
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right)
\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}.
\end{split}
\]

In-Text:
\(
\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right)
\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}.
\)

Subscript:
\(
\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right) X_{\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}}.
\)
\[
\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right) X_{\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}}.
\]

Sub-Subscript:
\(
\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right) X_{X_{\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}}}.
\)
\[
\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} - \frac{1}{x-1}
\right) X_{X_{\Alt<2>{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}{y}}}.
\]

Text-mode:
XXXX  \Alt<2>{aaaaa}{Ag}.


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The dots at the end are to visualize the constant width only.

[image: Result]

Comment: This looks excellent.  I will test it on Monday.

Comment: @Matthew: Did this work out for you?

Comment: I did not get around to trying it.  Next time...

Comment: Just had cause to use this and it worked just fine (though I did change the `\renewcommand\Alt` to `\newcommand\Alt` at the start before testing it).

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks. It should be `\newcommand\Alt`. The `\renewcommand\Alt` was still there from my experiment phase.

Comment: I find myself using this *again* and thinking that it deserves more than a paltry three votes ...

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I have to make a real package out of it and announce it here. Maybe then I get some more votes.

Comment: Do that!  I've already put it in a `.sty` file in my own `texmf` tree for easy use in various documents.  I called it `extalt`, most likely for `extended alt` (I chose the name back in May so the actual reasons are - thankfully - lost in the mists (and midsts) of time).

Comment: Thanks for these macros! They proved quite handy in a presentation I recently gave. I second the suggestion that you should package them. Also, if you do so, consider borrowing from [my slightly revised version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50251/1301) which supports Beamer's incremental overlay specifications.

Comment: @bcat I also second the suggestion that these macros should be incorporated into a package!  I found it useful to add an optional argument to specify the position of the smaller text within the larger box.  I added this small revision as an answer.  It was my first attempt at writing a nontrivial macro involving plain TeX, so I would appreciate feedback on any corrections you might have.

Comment: It seems to me that none of these work anymore; a simple fix is to change `box0` to `box2`.  Somehow, `alt` is messing with `box0` nowadays.

Answer (score 22):

The second `\Alt` command in [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13830/1301) is excellent; however, it can cause problems when used with Beamer's incremental overlay specifications (e.g., `<+>`). This is because Martin's implementation invokes the underlying `\alt` command using `\mathpalette`. `\mathpalette` internally uses `\mathchoice`, which actually typesets the contents given for each of the four math styles before deciding which to use in the final output.

### Example of the issue

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% [Paste Martin's second set of `\Alt` macros here.]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Some stuff\dots

      \pause

    \item An equation I'll reveal in pieces:
      \[
        \frac{-4}{2} + \frac{9}{3} =
        \Alt<+>{
          \vcenter{\hbox{ ?\thinspace?}}
        }{
          \frac{-4 + 9}{2 + 3} = 1.
        }
      \]

      \pause

    \item Some more stuff\dots
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this code yields a document with seven slides rather than the desired four, as TeX is executing the Beamer `\alt` macro---and thus incrementing the `beamerpauses` counter---four times rather than one.

### Solving the problem

Move the `\alt` invocation outside of `\mathpalette`/`\mathchoice`. Unfortunately, this means that the new `\Alt` command's arguments will be typeset eight times (four for each of the `\alt` macro's two arguments) rather than four times as in Martin's code, but the added overhead seems necessary to make `\Alt` behave the same as `\alt` with respect to incremental overlays.

Also, it's a minor thing, but adding a `\leavevmode` before typesetting the `\Alt` content box seems to make the command behave a bit less surprisingly in some cases, e.g., at the start of a list item.

### Revised code (supports incremental overlays)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For `\ifbool`, `\ifnumcomp`.

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Alt{\alt{\Alt@branch0}{\Alt@branch1}}

\newcommand\Alt@branch[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifbool{mmode}{%
    \mathchoice{%
      \Alt@math#1{\displaystyle}{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \Alt@math#1{\textstyle}{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \Alt@math#1{\scriptstyle}{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \Alt@math#1{\scriptscriptstyle}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }{%
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \sbox1{#3}%
    \Alt@typeset#1%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\Alt@math[4]{%
  \sbox0{$#2{#3}\m@th$}%
  \sbox1{$#2{#4}\m@th$}%
  \Alt@typeset#1%
}

\newcommand\Alt@typeset[1]{%
  \ifnumcomp{\wd0}{>}{\wd1}{%
    \def\setwider   ##1##2{##2##1##2 0}%
    \def\setnarrower##1##2{##2##1##2 1}%
  }{%
    \def\setwider   ##1##2{##2##1##2 1}%
    \def\setnarrower##1##2{##2##1##2 0}%
  }%
  \sbox2{}%
  \sbox3{}%
  \setwider2{\wd}%
  \setwider2{\ht}%
  \setwider2{\dp}%
  \setnarrower3{\ht}%
  \setnarrower3{\dp}%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\usebox#1}%
  \usebox2%
  \usebox3%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 for improving an already good answer a year later and the excellent explanations!

Comment: Thanks! Your version worked for me whereas neither of the ones by @MartinScharrer did.

Answer (score 12):

As a further revision to [Martin Scharrer's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13830/1301) and [bcat's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50251/6510) nifty answers, here is a version that allows one to specify the position (`l`, `c`, or `r`) of the smaller text within the larger box:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
% Detect mode. mathpalette is used to detect the used math style
\newcommand<>\Alt[3][l]{%
  \begingroup
    \providetoggle{Alt@before}%
    \alt#4{\toggletrue{Alt@before}}{\togglefalse{Alt@before}}%
    \ifbool{mmode}{%
      \expandafter\mathpalette
      \expandafter\math@Alt
    }{%
      \expandafter\make@Alt
    }%
    {{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}

% Un-brace the second argument (required because \mathpalette reads the three arguments as one
\newcommand\math@Alt[2]{\math@@Alt{#1}#2}

% Set the two arguments in boxes. The math style is given by #1. \m@th sets \mathsurround to 0.
\newcommand\math@@Alt[4]{%
  \setbox\z@ \hbox{$\m@th #1{#3}$}%
  \setbox\@ne\hbox{$\m@th #1{#4}$}%
  \@Alt{#2}%
}

% Un-brace the argument
\newcommand\make@Alt[1]{\make@@Alt#1}

% Set the two arguments into normal boxes
\newcommand\make@@Alt[3]{%
  \sbox\z@ {#2}%
  \sbox\@ne{#3}%
  \@Alt{#1}%
}

% Place one of the two boxes using \rlap and place a \phantom box with the maximum of the two boxes
\newcommand\@Alt[1]{%
  \setbox\tw@\null
  \ht\tw@\ifnum\ht\z@>\ht\@ne\ht\z@\else\ht\@ne\fi
  \dp\tw@\ifnum\dp\z@>\dp\@ne\dp\z@\else\dp\@ne\fi
  \wd\tw@\ifnum\wd\z@>\wd\@ne\dimexpr\wd\z@/2\relax\else\dimexpr\wd\@ne/2\relax\fi
  %
  \ifstrequal{#1}{l}{%
    \rlap{\iftoggle{Alt@before}{\usebox\z@}{\usebox\@ne}}%
    \copy\tw@
    \box\tw@
  }{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{c}{%
      \copy\tw@
      \clap{\iftoggle{Alt@before}{\usebox\z@}{\usebox\@ne}}%
      \box\tw@
    }{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{r}{%
        \copy\tw@
        \box\tw@
        \llap{\iftoggle{Alt@before}{\usebox\z@}{\usebox\@ne}}%
      }{%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Unlike bcat's macro, I use `\mathpalette` and avoid the bug in Martin's answer by toggling a flag inside `\alt`; the flag says whether the first or second argument of `\Alt` should be set.

This was my first attempt at writing a nontrivial macro involving plain TeX, so please let me know if there are better style practices I should use.

Comment: Scratch registers with an odd index (`\box1`, for instance) should be used only for global assignments. This is a recommended practice, not following it might lead to memory problems.

Comment: @egreg So I should not be using `\box\@ne` in this case?  Should I prefer the LaTeX style of `\newsavebox` etc. here, or is there a reason to stick to the plain TeX primitives for this macro?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use `\box\tw@` or `\box4`, `\box6`, `\box8`; in this case the scratch boxes seem to be correctly used. When in doubt allocate new ones.

Comment: Could you consider giving an example of how your new macro with the additional parameter is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `\vphantom` could help? The following code defines a macro `\altvphantom` which uses the normal `\alt` command and additionally inserts `\vphantom{<first argument>}` and `\vphantom{<second argument>}` to ensure a consistent vertical spacing and to prevent the jiggling:

```
\newcommand<>{\altvphantom}[2]{\alt#3{#1}{#2}\vphantom{#1}\vphantom{#2}}
```

Just add this line to your document and replace `\alt<2>{...}{...}` with `\altvphantom{...}{...}`, and the preceding lines will stop moving around.

**UPDATE:** If you do not want the last line to move left and right either, you can say `\usepackage{mathtools}` in the preamble and change the "`\alt`-line" to

```
\altvphantom<2>{\mathrlap{\frac{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x+3}}{x-1}}}{\mathrlap{y}}
```

Another possibilty would be to use the `fleqn` option: If you use `\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}`, all the equations will flush left, which solves the problem with the moving line, too.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Did you test it?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I tested it and it worked fine for me. I [uploaded the resulting PDF](http://www.mediafire.com/?zeq5e50c5hlrr25) for you.

Comment: @Seamus @diabonas thanks.  The vertical jiggling is gone (because the `\vphantom{#1}{#2}` stretches the line to have a height equal to the maximum of the two) but it still moves horizontally.

Comment: @Matthew @Seamus I've updated my solution to prevent this movement, too.

Comment: @Matthew: You could place the shorter one in a `\rlap` macro and use `\phantom{<longer one>}` to fill the correct amount of space.

Comment: @diabonas Ah I see. When I tested it, I used `\altvphantom{short}{loooooooooooooooooong} Jiggle` and "jiggle" moves around. I've not tried the `mathclap` edit yet

Comment: Oops, I wrote `\mathclap` instead of `\mathrlap`. Fixed that.

Comment: @Martin: right.  How could we test for width or get the maximum width automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of `alt` in `beamerbaseoverlay.sty`:

```
\def\alt{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@alt}{\beamer@alttwo}}
\long\def\beamer@alttwo#1#2{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@altget{#1}{#2}}{#1}}
\long\def\beamer@altget#1#2<#3>{%
  \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{#2}\def\beamer@doifinframe{#1}%
  {\beamer@masterdecode{#3}}\beamer@donow}
\long\def\beamer@alt<#1>#2#3{%
  \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{#3}\def\beamer@doifinframe{#2}%
  {\beamer@masterdecode{#1}}\beamer@donow}
```

Weirdly, `\uncover` is defined in terms of `\alt`:

```
\newcommand{\uncover}{\alt{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
```

So I suspect that putting `\beamer@fakeinvisible` and `\beamer@makeuncovered` at some point in a definition like that of `\alt` should work? But I couldn't work out where exactly to fit it in.