# Beamer Alt command working as Onslide

Tags: beamer, overlays

I try to have command working as `\alt` but with the behaviour of `\onslide`, I mean that doesn't move things around when appears.

I try the following solution, but at some point, there is a sliding from one line to the next. On my example, there is enough room for the word `zeros` but not for `\dots`.

Any idea to achieve that ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\Alt}[2][\dots]{\only<.-.>{#1}\onslide<+->{{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]

\item Ne pas oublier qu'un décimal peut s'écrire avec des
    \alt<+->{zéros inutiles si besoin.}{\dots}

\item Ne pas oublier qu'un décimal peut s'écrire avec des
    \Alt{zéros inutiles si besoin.}

\item Ne pas x x x oublier qu'un décimal peut s'écrire avec des
    \Alt{zéros inutiles si besoin.}

\end{enumerate}

Must not move.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13793/beamer-alt-command-like-visible-instead-of-like-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the problem with shrinking and stretching inter-word spaces, you could use `\RaggedRight` and to prevent the linebreak in front of the dots, try `\nolinebreak`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\RaggedRight

\item Ne pas x xxx x oublier qu'un décimal peut s'écrire avec des
\only<.>{\nolinebreak\dots }\visible<+->{zéros inutiles si besoin.}

\end{enumerate}

Must not move.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first slide is not a problem, as I have found asolution at the second, but this solution as an issue as you can see on the third slide. In termes of room, onslide, uncover and visible work the same: visible doesn't solve the problem on third slide. thank you.

Comment: @Tarass now I see what your problem is. Can you test my edited answer?

Comment: `\RaggedRight` is a problem because it cuts words, and I prefer not in a presentation. Even so, `des` moves now from one line the other. I excpect better ;-) Thank you for the lead `\nolinebreak`, I'll try in this direction.

Comment: `\nolinebreak\dots{} ` with a space at the end works fine. Add it in your answer. As you have found the clue of `\nolinebreack`.

Comment: @Tarass I added the space to my answer (it does not make any difference for me)

Comment: It will If you don't use raggedright. I prefer not to use it. Btw add also {} otherwise the space it eaten.

Comment: `\newcommand{\Alt}[2][\nolinebreak\dots\xspace]{\only<.>{#1}\onslide<+->{{#2}}}` works just fine.