# Beamer: replace displayed equation in an overlay

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays

[I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I searched and found related issues but haven't been able to solve my problem.]

I have a displayed equation and I want to replace it with another in an overlay *without affecting the surrounding text*. As shown below, I've tried six different ways, but none of them works. The surrounding text is fixed, which is what I want, in the "uncover", "uncover&overprint", and "overprint&onslide" solutions below but the equation shifts. In the other solutions, the surrounding text shifts.

I know absolute text positioning via the `textpos` package is a solution but it's tedious. I also think that giving a fake height to the less tall equation via `phantom` would work, too.

But, I thought that a simple solution would be already there, seeing that `uncover` and `overprint` are able to fix the position of the surrounding text.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1609]{beamer}
\begin{document}
%----
\begin{frame}{only}
Fixed text
\only<1>{\[\int f(x)\]}%
\only<2>{\[g(x)\]}%
fixed text.
\end{frame}
%---
\begin{frame}{uncover}
Fixed text
\uncover<1>{\[\int f(x)\]}%
\uncover<2>{\[g(x)\]}%
fixed text.
\end{frame}
%---
\begin{frame}{uncover \& overprint}
Fixed text
\begin{overprint}
\uncover<1>{\[\int f(x)\]}%
\uncover<2>{\[g(x)\]}%
fixed text.
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
%----
\begin{frame}{Overprint \& onslide}
Fixed text
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>{\[\int f(x)\]}%
\onslide<2>{\[g(x)\]}%
\end{overprint}
fixed text.
\end{frame}
%----
\begin{frame}{Overprint, only, \& onslide}
Fixed text
\begin{overprint}
\only<1>{\[\int f(x)\]}%
\onslide<2>{\[g(x)\]}%
\end{overprint}
fixed text.
\end{frame}
%----
\begin{frame}{alt}
Fixed text
\alt<2->%
{\[g(x)\]}%
{\[\int f(x)\]}%
fixed text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct combination is `overprint` and `\onslide`. Note: the `\onslide` commands are used like `\item` commands (i.e. *without* argument).

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1609]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Overprint \& onslide}
Fixed text
\begin{overprint}
  \onslide<1>
  \[\int f(x)\]

  \onslide<2>
  \[g(x)\]  
\end{overprint}
fixed text.
\end{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Of course it works!!  The only remaining question I have is, why is this? "the `\onslide` commands are used like `\item` commands (i.e. *without argument*)"  There must be use cases where the item-like use is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following is over-complicated for this one example, but if you do this often you might find the following approach useful, which defines a new command (from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63559/12212) for this purpose, `Alt` (note the capital 'A'):

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=1609]{beamer}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13793/beamer-alt-command-like-visible-instead-of-like-only
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand<>\Alt[2]{{%
    \sbox0{$\displaystyle #1$}%
    \sbox1{$\displaystyle #2$}%
    \alt#3%
        {\rlap{\usebox0}\vphantom{\usebox1}\hphantom{\ifnum\wd0>\wd1 \usebox0\else\usebox1\fi}}%
        {\rlap{\usebox1}\vphantom{\usebox0}\hphantom{\ifnum\wd0>\wd1 \usebox0\else\usebox1\fi}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{only}
Fixed text\bigskip{}
\[\Alt<2->{g(x)}{\int f(x)}\]%
fixed text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]