# Latex - Beamer: Applies the \cancel command only a specified slides

Tags: beamer, overlays, cancel

In `beamer`, overlay specifications can be used to make certain text
commands take effect at different times. For example, `\alert<2>` applies the alert command only on the second slide.

Is there an equivalent for the `cancel` command instead on the `alert` command ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/uncover-a-multiline-equation-with-beamer/11617#11617 as there I defined an overlay-aware version of the cancel command.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Great !!! This is exactly what I want :-) Thanks!

Comment: I've copied my code so that it's easier to find: the questions are sufficiently different that I don't think this is a duplicate.  It's just coincidence that my answer to that one involved the `cancel` stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Although my answer at [Uncover a multiline equation with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/uncover-a-multiline-equation-with-beamer/11617#11617) covers this case, the actual questions aren't duplicates so I'm copying the code here to make it easier for a casual "passer-by" to find it.)

Here's an overlay-aware version of the `\xcancel` command.  I've written it as a *wrapper* rather than a *replacement*, but it wouldn't be hard to do the latter instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand<>{\xxcancel}[1]{\alt#2{\xcancel{#1}\vphantom{#1}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{multline*}
        S(1,\dots,s) = \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{m_t} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{entropy estimate with correlation order}\, m_t} \\
        \xxcancel<2->{{} + \underbrace{\sum_{m=m_t+1}^{s} (-1)^{m+1} \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_m} I(i_1,\dots,i_m)}_{\text{correlations of order higher than}\, m_t} }
    \end{multline*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for this neat solution. I'm believe it's better to rather write `\newcommand<>{\xxcancel}[1]{\alt#2{\xcancel{#1}}{#1\vphantom{#1}}}` so that the vertical space is reserved before and not after the right overlay, at least it works better in my code without any shifting.