# Beamer: Uncover underbrace

Tags: math-mode, beamer

I've got an underbrace (`\underbrace{foo}_{bar}`) which I want to uncover (i.e. `foo` should be there from the beginning, while the underbrace and the `bar` should be uncovered on the next slide. I've tried the following, which (not surprisingly) doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Without uncover (this is what it should look like on the second subframe):
  \begin{displaymath}
    \underbrace{foo}_{bar}
  \end{displaymath}
  With uncover (doesn't work):
  \begin{displaymath}
    \uncover<2>{\underbrace}{foo}\uncover<2>{_{bar}}
  \end{displaymath}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the second `displaymath`, the underbrace is displayed before `foo` and the `bar` as index to `foo`, and moreover the underbrace is immediately visible.

Note that `\only` wouldn't be a solution because on one hand in my actual document I use `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` so the underbrace and the text below should be lightly visible from the beginning, and on the other hand `\only` would also not keep the space for the underbrace.

So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way to do that, is to use the definition of the transparency (15% Text foreground on the background and to avoid the “jumping” use as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/uncover-a-multiline-equation-with-beamer) the `overprint` environment.

Though you have to define your term that's `\underbrace`d twice and in my quick hack the transparency color is the one mentioned above, because i didn't find whether i can somehow get that by `\usebeamercolor`

```
\documentclass[transparent]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \begin{frame}%
        \begin{overprint}
            \onslide<1>\begin{displaymath}
                \color{normal text.fg!15!normal text.bg}
                \underbrace{\usebeamercolor[fg]{text}foo}_{bar}
            \end{displaymath}
            \onslide<2>\begin{displaymath}
                \underbrace{foo}_{bar}
            \end{displaymath}
        \end{overprint}
    \end{frame}%
\end{document}
```

And (thanks to @Andrew Stacey) the even shorter version just switching colors using `\only` (because `\color` is sensitive to that) would be

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \color{normal text.fg!15!normal text.bg}
        \only<2->{\color{normal text.fg}}
        \underbrace{\usebeamercolor[fg]{text}foo}_{bar}
    \end{displaymath}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Using `\textcolor` would be better if there are expressions after the term in the underbrace

Comment: How does one do this using `align`?

Answer (score 36):

Here's a solution that just uses `\onslide` (so that there's no need to know the precise definition of transparency):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \onslide<2-> \underbrace{ \onslide<1->
        foo
        \onslide<2-> }_{bar} \onslide<1->
        \text{some more stuff for slide 1}
    \end{displaymath}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be useful to stress that the last \onslide<1-> puts the settings back to the defaults. Otherwise, the other frames will appear transparent. In my beamer version, the last onslide lasts past the end of the frame.

Answer (score 16):

Based on Hendrik Vogt's answer, and for my needs, I created these commands to make my life easier:

```
\newcommand<>{\uncoverubrace}[2]{%
  \onslide#3 \underbrace{ \onslide<1->%
  #1%
  \onslide#3 }_{#2} \onslide<1->%
}
\newcommand<>{\uncoverobrace}[2]{%
  \onslide#3 \overbrace{ \onslide<1->%
  #1%
  \onslide#3 }^{#2} \onslide<1->%
}
```

Now the use is very simple:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
...
\begin{displaymath}
\uncoverubrace<2->{a_i}{\mathclap{\text{$N$ elements}}} =
\frac{
  \uncoverobrace<3->{b_j-b_i}{\mathclap{\text{$2N$ items needed}}}
}{2h}
\end{displaymath}
```

Room for improvement: allow relative overlay specifications (`<+->`).

Comment: Great solution! Easy to understand what is happening in the code and convenient to use.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Jellby's answer, I was not only able to simplify the code, but also patch the original `underbrace` using the `xparse` package such that it works with arbitrary `<overlay-specification>`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{amsmath, xparse, letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldunderbrace}{\underbrace}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\underbrace}{d<> m e{_}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
    % using global onlside flag, cf. p82 beamer manual v3.59
    \oldunderbrace{#2\onslide<#1>}_{#3}\onslide%
  }{% ELSE
    \oldunderbrace{#2}_{#3}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\alt<1,3>{LINKS}{ZWO}}
\begin{block}<+->{}
\begin{align*}
\underbrace<+->{\text{\color{green} LINKS!}}_{\color{red} \text{ZWO!}}
\underbrace<+->{\text{\color{green} LINKS!}}_{\color{red} \text{DREI!}}
\underbrace<+->{\text{\color{green} LINKS!}}_{\color{red} \text{VIER!}}
\end{align*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I guess if one wanted one could even built-in an `\@ifclassloaded{beamer}` in order to automagically ignore the `<>` when other classes are loaded.

For `\overbrace` it is a bit different, see my other post here: [Beamer: Uncover underbrace & overbrace weird behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565971/119955)

Comment: I'd say this should be the preferred solution.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the equivalent with ``overbrace`` does not seem to work

``\LetLtxMacro{\oldoverbrace}{\overbrace}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\overbrace}{d<> m e{^}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
     % using global onlside flag, cf. p82 beamer manual v3.59
     \oldoverbrace{#2\onslide<3->}^{#3}\onslide%
  }{% ELSE
     \oldoverbrace{#2}^{#3}
   }%
}%``

Comment: the issue seems to come from ``\overbrace`` and its interaction with ``\onslide``, it doesn't react similarly to ``\overbrace``, for instance ``\underbrace{a\onslide<2->}_{b}\onslide``but not ``\overbrace{a\onslide<2->}^{b}\onslide``

Comment: ok the problem is explained  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565971/118411), weird effect

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from the proposition of Hyperplane, here is the solution for `\overbrace`. As explained at [Beamer: Uncover underbrace & overbrace weird behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565971/beamer-uncover-underbrace-overbrace-weird-behaviour) `\overbrace` behaves differently from `\underbrace`, the code had thus to be adapted a bit.

```
\LetLtxMacro{\oldoverbrace}{\overbrace}
 \DeclareDocumentCommand{\overbrace}{d<> m e{^}}{%
   \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
     % using global onlside flag, cf. p82 beamer manual v3.59
     \onslide<#1>\oldoverbrace{\onslide #2}^{#3}\onslide%
   }{% ELSE
     \oldoverbrace{#2}^{#3}
   }%
}%
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a litte bit simpler, so it might be worth sharing. The idea is to combine alt with vphantom. This is how the command is defined:

```
\newcommmand<>{\underbraceonslide}{\alt#3{\underbrace{#1}{#2}}{\vphantom{\underbrace{#1}{#2}}#1}}
```

It uses beamer's overlay specifications, e.g.

```
\underbraceonslide<2->{ \frac{1}{n} }{\to 0}
```