# Uncovering pgfplots in beamer one by one does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, overlays

I'm trying to show an equation that has two components. For each component, I would like to explain each term one by one, so was able to use `\underbrace` to uncover component by component following [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/beamer-uncover-underbrace). The problem is that I can't uncover the corresponding plot in the tikzpicture one by one (they all appear at the end.

In other words, the first figure should appear together with the first underbrace, and similarly with the second underbrace. Is this an issue on my definition of visible in `tiksset` or it simply can't be done?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, arrows, external, patterns}


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[ x  = \onslide<2-> \underbrace{ \onslide<1-> a \onslide<2-> }_{\text{(A)}}  \onslide<1-> -  \onslide<3-> \underbrace{  \onslide<1->b \onslide<3-> }_{\text{(B)}} \]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 3,
        },
        unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
        xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
        ymin=0,ymax=1.8,
        width = 4cm,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        xmajorticks=false,
        ymajorticks=false
        ]

    \nextgroupplot[]

    \addplot [visible on=<2->, thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black, 
                fill opacity=0.05] coordinates {
        (-1.5,0)  (-1.5,1.5)  (-0.5, 0.5) (0.5, 0.) (1.5, 1.5) (1.5,0) };

    \nextgroupplot[]

    \addplot [visible on=<3->, thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black, 
                fill opacity=0.05] coordinates {
        (-1.5,0)  (-1.5,1.5) (-0.5,0) (0.5,0) (1.5, 1.5) (1.5,0) };

    \nextgroupplot[ymax=1]

    \addplot [thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black, 
                fill opacity=0.05] coordinates {
        (-0.5, 0) (-0.5,0.5) (0.5,0)};

    \end{groupplot}    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from you `\onslide` construction. You had an `\onslide<3->` at its end such that everything after only appears from slide 3 on. To cure that, you only need to add an `\onslide<1->` after the equation. I also changed the filling to `black!5` as your opacity directive overrides the `opacity=0` trick that is used to make the plots invisible on the early slides.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds, plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, arrows, external, patterns}


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[ x  = \onslide<2-> \underbrace{ \onslide<1-> a \onslide<2-> }_{\text{(A)}}  \onslide<1-> -  \onslide<3-> \underbrace{  \onslide<1->b \onslide<3-> }_{\text{(B)}} \]
\onslide<1->

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 3,
        },
        unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
        xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
        ymin=0,ymax=1.8,
        width = 4cm,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        xmajorticks=false,
        ymajorticks=false
        ]

    \nextgroupplot[]

    \addplot [visible on=<2->, thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black!5] coordinates {
        (-1.5,0)  (-1.5,1.5)  (-0.5, 0.5) (0.5, 0.) (1.5, 1.5) (1.5,0) };

    \nextgroupplot[]

    \addplot [visible on=<3->, thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black!5] coordinates {
        (-1.5,0)  (-1.5,1.5) (-0.5,0) (0.5,0) (1.5, 1.5) (1.5,0) };

    \nextgroupplot[ymax=1]

    \addplot [thick,color=black,mark=none,fill=black!5] coordinates {
        (-0.5, 0) (-0.5,0.5) (0.5,0)};

    \end{groupplot}    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]