# Beamer uncovering items which should be invisible

Tags: beamer

## `invisible` shows items that are hidden with `transparent`

After trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60381/106804) to "[Beamer: Uncover underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/beamer-uncover-underbrace)", I find that when I change `transparent` to `invisible` in `\setbeamercovered` I am not getting the result I would have expected. When `transparent`,  I get the desired uncovering order, but this seems not to be preserved as I move to `invisible`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % Change to invisible. 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
\onslide<1->{\text{Something} & = \text{Slide 1 onwards} \\[1em]}
& \qquad \onslide<2->{+} \onslide<3-> \underbrace{ \onslide<2->
\text{Slide 2 onwards}
\onslide<3-> }_{\text{Slide 3 onwards}} \onslide<2->
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a missing set of `{}` as well as the `\notag` command to stop `(2)` from showing up on the first slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{invisible} % Change to invisible. 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
\onslide<1->{\text{Something} & = \text{Slide 1 onwards} \\[1em]}
& \qquad \onslide<2->{+} \onslide<3->{\underbrace{ \onslide<2->  % <----- Added {
\text{Slide 2 onwards}
\onslide<3-> }_{\text{Slide 3 onwards}}\\} \notag % <----- Added }, \\ and \notag
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had my original in an `align*` so overlooked the `\notag`. Although this fixes the problem, is there an explanation as to the behaviour in the original question?