# Beamer: Uncover underbrace & overbrace weird behaviour

Tags: beamer, math-mode, overlays, xparse

I recently needed to cover some over- and underbrace and found a solution here: [Beamer: Uncover underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/beamer-uncover-underbrace)

However, I was not 100% satisfied with the offered solutions, in particular, my goal was to create commands `\underbrace<>{}_{}` and `\overbrace<>{}^{}` that should just work like you'd expect, with no additional restrictions on overlay specifications or content. I succeeded doing this for `underbrace` [[A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565866/119955)], although I do not know exactly why my solution works (I was very surprised it did!) However, to my even bigger surprise, it does not work with `overbrace`! However, it turned out it would again with a slight modification - which again I do not understand why it works at all in one case but not the other. The crucial part of the code is:

```latex
% underbrace version A
\onslide<#1>\underbrace{\onslide<1->#2}_{#3}\onslide
% underbrace version B
\underbrace{#2\onslide<#1>}_{#3}\onslide
% overbrace version A
\onslide<#1>\overbrace{\onslide<1->#2}^{#3}\onslide
% overbrace version B
\overbrace{#2\onslide<#1>}^{#3}\onslide
```

The only combination that works as intended is underbrace version B and overbrace version A. But why? **EDIT:** I just noted, for `\overset` and `\underset` one has to do it the other way round! Full MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ubraceA}{d<> m e{_}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
    \onslide<#1>\underbrace{\onslide<1->#2}_{#3}\onslide
  }{% ELSE
    \underbrace{#2}_{#3}
  }%
}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ubraceB}{d<> m e{_}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
    \underbrace{#2\onslide<#1>}_{#3}\onslide
  }{% ELSE
    \underbrace{#2}_{#3}
  }%
}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\obraceA}{d<> m e{^}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
      \onslide<#1>\overbrace{\onslide<1->#2}^{#3}\onslide
  }{% ELSE
    \overbrace{#2}^{#3}
  }%
}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\obraceB}{d<> m e{^}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% IF <overlay-specification> given
    \overbrace{#2\onslide<#1>}^{#3}\onslide
  }{% ELSE
    \overbrace{#2}^{#3}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{underA, overA}
\begin{align*}
  \ubraceA<5->{p(x\mid y)}_{\text{posterior}}
  = \frac{\obraceA<2->{p(y\mid x)}^{\text{likelihood}}
  \,\obraceA<3->{p(x)}^{\text{prior}}
  }{\ubraceA<4->{p(y)}_{\text{evidence}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{underA, overB}
\begin{align*}
  \ubraceA<5->{p(x\mid y)}_{\text{posterior}}
  = \frac{\obraceB<2->{p(y\mid x)}^{\text{likelihood}}
  \,\obraceB<3->{p(x)}^{\text{prior}}
  }{\ubraceA<4->{p(y)}_{\text{evidence}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{underB, overA}
\begin{align*}
  \ubraceB<5->{p(x\mid y)}_{\text{posterior}}
  = \frac{\obraceA<2->{p(y\mid x)}^{\text{likelihood}}
  \,\obraceA<3->{p(x)}^{\text{prior}}
  }{\ubraceB<4->{p(y)}_{\text{evidence}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{underB, overB}
\begin{align*}
  \ubraceB<5->{p(x\mid y)}_{\text{posterior}}
  = \frac{  \obraceB<2->{p(y\mid x)}^{\text{likelihood}}
  \,\obraceB<3->{p(x)}^{\text{prior}}
  }{\ubraceB<4->{p(y)}_{\text{evidence}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For overbrace option a, I got good result with ``\onslide<#1>\overbrace{\onslide a}^{b}``for option A. This avoids using ``<1->``

Comment: [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/documentation) mentions that `\pause` (which uses `\onslide` internally) doesn't work in `align`, p 78 (probably related to its multiple processing of the environment due to measuring). So, I assume, `\onslide` therefore may cause difficulty within `align`.