# beamer: delay showing underbrace

Tags: beamer

On my beamer slides, I want to put \underbrace around an equation and a remark under the underbrace.  I want to show the equation first, and then the underbrace AND the remark together in the next slide.  Using \visible I can do that for the remark, but how do I do that for the underbrace as well?  Here is a NON-working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \visible<1->{$
    \visible<2->{
       \underbrace{ \visible<1->{A+B=C} }_{\text{show later}}
      }
    $}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This post  [Beamer: Uncover underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/beamer-uncover-underbrace)  answers the related question where we wrap underbrace around plain text, but I got weird bugs if I make the obvious modifcation.   Here is a NON-working example based on this post:

```
\documentclass[tansparent]{beamer}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\visible<2->{\begin{displaymath}
  \color{normal text.fg!5!normal text.bg}
        \only<3->{\color{normal text.fg}}
          \underbrace{\usebeamercolor[fg]{$A+B=C$}}_{bar}
   \end{displaymath}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\only<1>{A+B=C}$
$ \visible<2->{
       \underbrace{ A+B=C}_{\text{show later}}
      }
    $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```