# Uncovering lines in an equation in split environment

Tags: beamer, math-mode

How does one uncover lines in a multi-line equation one by one? I have taken a careful look at the answers provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/uncover-a-multiline-equation-with-beamer?rq=1). It hasn't solved my problem. For example, my equation is the following and I want to uncover the two lines one at a time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Steady State Relationship between $O^m, O^a$}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\rho +\sigma\bar\omega^m)O^m&=O^a-\phi L^a-\phi L^r-\eta O^r\\
\frac{O^m}{O^a}&=\frac{1-\phi l^a-(\phi l^r+\eta) O^r/O^a}{\rho +\sigma\bar\omega^m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The linked question/solution does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

The following inserts the math content using `\alt`. `\phantom` is used to maintain the appropriate spacing on slides where the content is not needed. All of this is contained within a macro `\disponslide{<overlay>}{<stuff>}`, which prints `<stuff>` using the overlay specification `<overlay>`, and `\phantom{<stuff>}` outside of `<overlay>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\disponslide}[2]{%
  \alt<#1>{#2}{\phantom{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Steady State Relationship between $O^m, O^a$}
  \begin{align}
    (\rho +\sigma\bar\omega^m)O^m    &= O^a-\phi L^a-\phi L^r-\eta O^r \\
    \disponslide{2}{\frac{O^m}{O^a}} & \disponslide{2}{{}=\frac{1-\phi l^a-(\phi l^r+\eta) O^r/O^a}{\rho +\sigma\bar\omega^m}}\only<1>{\notag}
  \end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You *have* to split the overlay between the alignment positions `&`.

Comment: The equation number is wrong. If you add a numbered equation after the `align` environment (without overlays), you'll see the problem.

Comment: @LeoLiu: Yes. Then one should use `...\only<1>{\notag\refstepcounter{equation}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The overlay specifications do not work inside `amsmath` environments, including `split`.   Indeed the `beamer` documentation says:

> \pause[⟨number ⟩] This command causes the text following it to be
>   shown only from the next slide on, or, if the optional ⟨number⟩ is
>   given, from the slide with the number ⟨number⟩. If the optional
>   ⟨number⟩ is given, the counter beamerpauses is set to this number.
>   This command uses the \onslide command, internally. This command does
>   not work inside amsmath environments like align, since these do really
>   wicked things.

Instead I suggest you display this as two separate equations - in the given example the alignment is not essential.

If such displays are necessary you could consider the `equationarray` environment from `eqnarray`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Steady State Relationship between $O^m, O^a$}
\begin{equationarray}{r@{}l}
    (\rho +\sigma\bar\omega^m)O^m&{}=O^a-\phi L^a-\phi L^r-\eta
    O^r\pause \\
    \frac{O^m}{O^a}&{}=\frac{1-\phi l^a-(\phi l^r+\eta) O^r/O^a}{\rho
    +\sigma\bar\omega^m}
  \end{equationarray}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you see, will have to take more care with spacing near alignment points.  For example, writing `&{}=` instead of `&=`, above.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: That was just one equation for an example, there are others where alignment becomes essential to keep track of the steps involved. I was asking a more general question. So, your answer implies that I leave the amsmath option? And then use \uncover?